# libart.so crash on Android 5.1

Tags: android, native

There are lots of native crashes in my app, only in **5.0 or 5.1** android system, the crash trace are bellow:

```
SIGBUS(BUS_ADRERR):
#00 pc 0022dece /system/lib/libart.so (art::StackVisitor::WalkStack(bool) +209)
#01 pc 00237915 /system/lib/libart.so (_jobject* art::Thread::CreateInternalStackTrace<false>(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&) const +56)
#02 pc 002081b3 /system/lib/libart.so (art::Throwable_nativeFillInStackTrace(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*) +18)
#03 pc 00000c1d /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
```

[image: crash stack traces]

Does anyone else have met this problem before ? what is  `/data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat` ?  Any help on how to proceed would be appreciated ! Thanks